# PostGIS, update table, set "true" on the largest area with same ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table in Postgres/PostGis with the following columns:
Id (PK), officialId, areaname, is_mainarea (bool), geom (Polygon)
The rows in the data could have the same name and official id, but different geom. There are one or more minor "satellite areas " to a "main area" that have the same name and id.
Example:

```
Id   officialId  areaname  is_mainarea  geom
3034 217044      Boda      false        POLYGON(xxxx)
4381 217044      Boda      false        POLYGON(xxxx)
4382 217044      Boda      false        POLYGON(xxxx)
3047 217026      Djura     false        POLYGON(xxxx)
4516 217026      Djura     false        POLYGON(xxxx)
```

What I want to do is to update the table so that the row with the largest area of the ones with the same official id has "true" in is_mainarea. So, in the example above is_mainarea should be true on row with Id 3034 and 2047.

Is there a way to do this with just SQL?

Example of polygons. I would need to find a way to set is_mainarea=true for the larger of the polygons with the same officialid.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That query should help you:

```sql
WITH max_area_id AS (
  select id 
  from table_name
  group by id, officialId 
  having ST_AREA(geom) = max(ST_AREA(geom))
)
update table_name
set is_mainarea=true
from max_area
where table.id = max_area_id.id
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get true on all rows with that query. I added a picture to my original question if that clears up anything of what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following adjustment to Netanels answer:

```
WITH max_area_id AS (
      select id
        from geo.geoareas as a
        and a.id = (select id from geo.geoareas as b where a.officialid = b.officialid order by st_area(b.geom) desc limit 1)
    )
update geo.geoareas a
    set ismainarea=true
    from max_area_id
    where a.id = max_area_id.id
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).